# Can EthereumJ connect with geth in my private network?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, private-blockchain, ethereumj

```
I0908 10:55:59.650726 p2p/peer.go:301] Peer c944075180d7ede0 172.21.101.100:30303: Starting protocol eth/62 I0908 10:55:59.650903 eth/handler.go:252] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62]: peer connected [Ethereum(J)/v1.3.0/Linux/Release/Java/Dev] I0908 10:55:59.661051 eth/handler.go:264] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62]: adding peer I0908 10:55:59.661129 eth/downloader/downloader.go:258] Registering peer   c944075180d7ede0 I0908 10:56:03.817518 eth/downloader/downloader.go:284] Attempting synchronisation: c944075180d7ede0, head [ba255796鈥, TD 118389115 I0908 10:56:03.817640 eth/downloader/downloader.go:320] Block synchronisation started I0908 10:56:03.817812 eth/downloader/downloader.go:381] Synchronising with the network using: c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] I0908 10:56:03.817894 eth/downloader/downloader.go:992] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 20s]: retrieving remote chain height I0908 10:56:03.818131 eth/peer.go:252] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 1 headers from ba255796, skipping 0 (reverse = false) I0908 10:56:03.831309 eth/fetcher/fetcher.go:258] [eth/62] filtering 1 headers I0908 10:56:03.831494 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1040] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 20s]: looking for common ancestor I0908 10:56:03.831612 eth/peer.go:259] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 192 headers from #0, skipping 0 (reverse = false) I0908 10:56:03.887721 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1130] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 20s]: common ancestor: #0 [cb02ff60鈥 I0908 10:56:03.888030 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1358] Downloading block bodies from #1 I0908 10:56:03.887955 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1406] Downloading node state data I0908 10:56:03.888162 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1382] Downloading receipts from #1 I0908 10:56:03.888211 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1211] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 20s]: directing header downloads from #1 I0908 10:56:03.888432 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1226] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 20s]: fetching 192 skeleton headers from #1 I0908 10:56:03.888523 eth/peer.go:259] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 128 headers from #192, skipping 191 (reverse = false)

I0908 10:56:03.926892 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1327] Filling up skeleton from #1 I0908 10:56:04.027509 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1600] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 20s]: requesting header(s) from #1 I0908 10:56:04.027692 eth/peer.go:259] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 192 headers from #1, skipping 0 (reverse = false) I0908 10:56:04.083701 eth/downloader/queue.go:1006] Peer c944075180d7ede0: last header #192 [7c2bc365] broke skeleton structure, expected a5282625(#383) I0908 10:56:04.083780 eth/downloader/queue.go:1027] Peer c944075180d7ede0: skeleton filling from header #1 not accepted I0908 10:56:04.083870 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1523] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 20s]: header delivery failed: delivery not accepted I0908 10:56:04.083959 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1600] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 20s]: requesting header(s) from #193 I0908 10:56:04.084057 eth/peer.go:259] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 192 headers from #193, skipping 0 (reverse = false) I0908 10:56:04.139558 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1521] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 345.86/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: delivered 192 header(s) I0908 10:56:04.139657 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1600] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 345.86/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: requesting header(s) from #385 I0908 10:56:04.139749 eth/peer.go:259] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 192 headers from #385, skipping 0 (reverse = false) I0908 10:56:04.194157 eth/downloader/queue.go:1006] Peer c944075180d7ede0: last header #576 [fd0f4df9] broke skeleton structure, expected 0593cd74 I0908 10:56:04.194216 eth/downloader/queue.go:1027] Peer c944075180d7ede0: skeleton filling from header #385 not accepted I0908 10:56:04.194244 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1523] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: header delivery failed: delivery not accepted I0908 10:56:04.194314 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1600] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: requesting header(s) from #577 I0908 10:56:04.194398 eth/peer.go:259] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 192 headers from #577, skipping 0 (reverse = false) I0908 10:56:04.241955 eth/downloader/queue.go:1027] Peer c944075180d7ede0: skeleton filling from header #577 not accepted I0908 10:56:04.242007 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1523] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: header delivery failed: delivery not accepted I0908 10:56:04.242079 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1600] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: requesting header(s) from #769 I0908 10:56:04.242162 eth/peer.go:259] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 192 headers from #769, skipping 0 (reverse = false) I0908 10:56:04.251019 eth/downloader/queue.go:1027] Peer c944075180d7ede0: skeleton filling from header #769 not accepted I0908 10:56:04.251067 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1523] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: header delivery failed: delivery not accepted I0908 10:56:04.251168 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1600] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: requesting header(s) from #961 I0908 10:56:04.251253 eth/peer.go:259] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 192 headers from #961, skipping 0 (reverse = false) I0908 10:56:04.260887 eth/downloader/queue.go:1027] Peer c944075180d7ede0: skeleton filling from header #961 not accepted I0908 10:56:04.260934 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1523] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: header delivery failed: delivery not accepted I0908 10:56:04.261006 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1600] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: requesting header(s) from #1153 I0908 10:56:04.261086 eth/peer.go:259] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [eth/62] fetching 192 headers from #1153, skipping 0 (reverse = false) I0908 10:56:04.270794 eth/downloader/queue.go:1027] Peer c944075180d7ede0: skeleton filling from header #1153 not accepted I0908 10:56:04.270874 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1523] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: header delivery failed: delivery not accepted I0908 10:56:04.270951 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1600] Peer c944075180d7ede0 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss 0, rtt 18.005551392s]: requesting header(s) from #1345
```